# Counting Number of Strominoes (Extension of Dominoes)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The number of dominoes in a Sino-European set (0 to 6 dots) is
$$21 + 7 = 28,$$
where the $21$ is the number of pairs that can be formed, and $7$ is doubles.

Now suppose we extend this to Strominos ($3 \times 1$) rectangles, with 3 distinct squares.
Dominoes have rotational symmetry of order 2, and we want to keep the symmetry, so paint the dots on the strominos so that the tromino also has order of rotational symmetry 2.

Now, what is the number of distinct strominonoes where the number of dots is 0-6?

One method is to say:
There are 28 dominoes. In each distinct domino, introduce a middle square (7 possibilities), and hence the number of strominos is
$$28 \times 7=196$$

Second method is to say:
Number of distinct strominos is:
$$(7 \times 7 \times 7 - 7)/2 + 7 = 336/2 + 7 = 168 + 7 = 175,$$
where the single color strominos are not repeated, and do not need to be divided, but all others are overcounted by 2, and hence need to do be divided.

These two should give the same answer.
What is the actual (correct) answer?

Note: The stromino notation comes from https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2020_INMO_Problems/Problem_6

But this problem is not related to that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove the 'single color' strominoes (e.g. $000, 111$), you also need to remove the symmetric $010,020$, etc.., as these are also doubled up.

Your calculation then becomes:

$$\frac{(7^3-7^2)}{2}+7^2=\frac{(343-49)}{2}+7^2=\frac{294}{2}+49=147+49=196$$